# Trace which function requires a given linked-library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have some linked-libraries which are required in my path at runtime and I'm not sure as to why they're needed. I would like to be able to find a sort of traceback of where they're being called from.

So say I have a main in myprogram.c (language shouldn't matter) which invokes functions `func1()` and `func2()` which come from the shared libraries libshared1.so and libshared2.so respectively. Is there a way, from the executable, to find that `func2()` was(/should be) loaded from libshared2.so?

Ideally I'm looking for a linux command which I input `command ./myprogram` and would output something along the lines of:

```
myprogram.c:1 func1() loaded from libshared1.so at ~/libshared1.so
myprogram.c:2 func2() from libshared2.so at ~/libraries/libshared2.so
myprogram.c:3 func1() loaded from libshared1.so at ~/libshared1.so
```

or `command ./myprogram libshared1.so` giving:

```
libshared1.so used in myprogram in:
func1() (myprogram.c:1)
func1() (myprogram.c:3)
```

As far as I can tell, ltrace, strace, and ldd do not give this information.

Bonus if it works even if I forgot to include one of the shared libraries in the path.

Comment: You can disassemble the file using `objdump`, and in the output, look for `call` statements.

Comment: For a small program, yes, but without a clear way to distinguish if the call is from a shared library  then it's not very useful.